# Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: winextras

Tags: c++, ubuntu-14.04, qt5.5

I am going to compile 
"MUSICPLAYER" : http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwinextras-musicplayer-example.html  EXAMPLE of QT, on QT 5.5 , and now I have this 
**error: Unknown module(s) in QT: winextras**

Answer (score 1):

Linux versions of Qt don't have `winextras` module, because that module is for Windows specific features, which aren't really cross platform.

Quote from the page you link to:

> The Music Player example demonstrates how to use the various features
>   provided by the QtWinExtras module.

Similar module for X11 platforms like desktop Linux is [`x11extras` module](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtx11extras-index.html). Note "similar", as it has different stuff in it of course, because anything cross-platform is generally in the other modules.

Comment: At fist Thanks for your response, So there is not any way to compile and use this example on linux?

Comment: Well, theoretically you could use MinGW cross-compiler (compiling for Windows on Linux) and then run the resulting application under Wine. For practical purposes, it's not useful.

Comment: Note that there is the generic version of the Music player example (linked to from the page you link to), which works for Linux.